# Python django filter get all records modified within Last 10 Minutes

Tags: django, filter

Using  django I attempting to get All records that are modified based on modificationtime  field in last 10 minutes

```
class Status(models.Model):
.
.
.
 modificationtime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="modificationtime", null=True, blank=True, )
```

setttings.py consists of following entries

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True

ten_minutes_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10)
changedstatuslist = Status.objects.filter(Q(modificationtime__lte=ten_minutes_ago))
```

but changedstatuslist does not appears to be showing correct data. what  modification/correction is needed above code so as to get all status objects records that are modified in last 10 minutes.

Comment: changedstatuslist = Status.objects.filter(modificationtime__gte=ten_minutes_ago)

Comment: This correction suggested by  LaCharcaSoftware works as expected and is accepted answer Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [@LaCharcaSoftware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12555280/lacharcasoftware), you seem to be currently getting all the records modified before the last ten minutes. To get all the records modified after the last ten minutes:

```py
changedstatuslist = Status.objects.filter(Q(modificationtime__lte=ten_minutes_ago))
```